# Dynamically div scrolling on mouse wheel both horizontal and vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a div name demo and i want to make this div scrolling when it exceeds it defined size . Also i want to track the height and width of div so that next time when i open my project it automayically assign that height and width to the div

Right now am giving hard coded double size of div height and width. Please let me know how it is possible and thanks in advance.

My div css is as follows

```
#demo{
   top:80px;
   position: absolute;
   background-image:url(../images/bg6.jpg);
   width: 2000px;
   height: 1500px;
   overflow: auto;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Consider splitting your question into two, this way it is overly broad and on two unrelated topics.

Comment: "*i want to track the height and width*": Is your div resizable?

Comment: why width is hardcoded that way to fix the width and height, can't you use width and height to `100%` of the parent elem.

Comment: Hi, actually my requirement is that my project is of drag and drop elements on a sheet. So i define a div in which elements are drop. Now the problems arises when  my div becomes scrollable. When i reopen my project then the div open with its default size as open in starting .No scrollable is dere and my all elements lost there actual position and puzzled as div not open to that size when its designed. I have hardcded the width and height here for a temporary solution as one i am facing this problem and another that i know my elemnts would not exceeds to that size Pls help me cop out this prob

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix the div in the screen, there is no need to track the scroll, you can make it fixed:

```
#demo{
   top:80px;
   position: fixed;
   ...
}
```

> *"Also i want to track the height and width of div so that next time when i open my project it automatically assign that height and width to the div"*

You need to save those values, there are some ways to do that;

- **Database** (by calling a php file for instance, you can associate that size to an user account, login etc.)
- **Cookies** (its the easiest way, but the user will not have the data in other computers, and it will be wiped on a browser cache clean)
- **HTML5** api has also methods to keep data.

Comment: Yeah I got the point i have to store position of height and width to DB . So that next time when i open again the same project it will automatically assign

Comment: Exactly! do you already have an user management system? You can opt by storing in a DB or in cookies, depending on your needs...